# Floating Objects

Tags: animation, physics, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I want to do an animation where a door opens and objects float.
How can I do it?

[image]

Reference: https://www.instagram.com/reel/Cn4rLCvKs-X/?igshid=MzRlODBiNWFlZA%3D%3D

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *Rigid Body* physics: Give a *Rigid Body (Passive)* to the 4 doors, activate the *Animated* option, give a *Rigid Body (Active)* to the balloons, in the *Scene* panel > *Gravity*, set the gravity on Z to 0.5, create some *Force Fields* in order to agitate the balloons a bit:

[image]

Comment: What if I want it to go horizontal? Should I have a force to make them follow that direction?

Comment: You can set a gravity on X and Y as well, or create a wind force field